# PHP Check subdomain sensitive to IP address

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, ip, subdomain

I'm having some issue with something that seemed simple to me at first, but is now proving very difficult. Maybe I'm over thinking it - would love your help.

**Overview:**
I have a web application with two interfaces (1 for *clients* and 1 for *customers*). All *customers* get routed one way and all *clients* get routed another. I determine which login screen to show based on their subdomain. *customers* get the base domain (+www) and *clients* go to [*clientName*].example.com

**Problem:**
I was determining this before by doing string manipulations on env("HTTP_HOST") -- see code below. However, this now poses an issue when using local IPs (for testing with other devices/ people). My code, which looks for '.' in the host environment fails because IPs have 3 dots and '*localhost*' has 0

These are the different naming parameters I've established and how I'd like the route...

```
CUSTOMER ----------------------------- CLIENT
                xyz.example.com ------>
        <------ www.example.com
        <------ example.com

                xyz.localhost   ------>
        <------ www.localhost
        <------ localhost

                xyz.192.168.X.X ------>
        <------ www.192.168.X.X
        <------ 192.168.X.X
```

I could be really over thinking this and am hoping there's some simple Php function like "get_subdomain()" that will do this for me. But I'm not seeing it and would really love some help.

Thanks!

**Current Code:**

```
$host = env("HTTP_HOST");
$group = null;

// if there is exactly one dot IE example[dot]com then there is no subdomain
if(substr_count($host,'.')==1){
    $group = 'customer'
}else{ // there is a subdomain
    $subdomain = substr($host, 0, strpos($host, "."));
    if($subdomain=='www'){
        $group = 'customer'
    }else{
        $group = 'client'
    }
}
```

CakePhp if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer does not seem to avoid your specific question, but it seems to me that you are inviting alternatives in your question. I do think you are over-thinking the solution, especially since it is primarily to assist you in your test environment.

What I suggest is that you define your own local domains for testing instead of using IP Addresses. So for example you could (in your hosts file or equivalent) define:

```
xyzclient.mylocaldomain  192.168.1.1 [or whatever your local ip is]
www.mylocaldomain        192.168.1.1 
xyz.localhost            192.168.1.1
www.localhost            192.168.1.1
```

Then you don't need to code any differently for local or live environments. Just in case: [this guide](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts) to setting up and configuring local domains may be useful.

Comment: That's how I was doing it, but the whole reason I noticed a problem is I'm developing a mobile app to accompany the web app. This mobile app needs to talk to my local machine via the LAN IP I supply it. As far as I know, mobile phones don't have a host file I can edit. So unless I hardcode it in the cakephp bootstrap itself I need a better way to determine the subdomain.

Comment: I believe it is possible to edit the hosts file on an Android phone, although it will require some 3rd party apps. This discussion for example: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=514698

Comment: Thanks will look into more.